# Finding an upper bound for N in R(T) and showing that no least upper bound for N exists in R(T).

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have been stuck in trying to understand and prove this statement for a while.
Given that $R(T)^+ = \{\dfrac{p(t)}{q(t)} \in R(t) \mid \dfrac{p_n}{q_n}>0\}$ gives the rational functions a structure of an ordered field,

1. Show that the element $t \in R(t)$ is an upper bound for the set of natural numbers $N \subseteq R(t)$
2. Show that the set of natural numbers $N \subseteq R(t)$ has no least upper bound in $R(t)$.

My initial approach was to try to prove it by contradiction by assuming that $t<n$ for some $n$, but I was not able to show that $n-t \in R(t)$ is impossible, so I am stuck.

I don't fully understand how we are comparing elements in $N$ and elements in $R(t) \backslash N$. It seems like all we are considering is the leading coefficients, which would make it seem like if the leading coefficient were big enough, then a natural number like 2 could be bigger than a t, because the leading coefficient seems to be larger. I don't think my intuition is correct about the ordering of rational functions.

Any help in clarifying the question or helping me understand the intuition behind ordering in the rational functions would be thoroughly appreciated!